# how to read a .coe extension file image in embedded c

Tags: c#, embedded

i need syntax to read an image of .coe extension file in "embedded c" coding. it is used to dump this image to FPGA and to display that image on to the another VGA monitor.

Comment: Did you try a Google search on "coe file syntax"?

Comment: Why is this tagged C#?  No mention of it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The `.coe` file format is documented on Xilinx's website, here:

http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx11/cgn_r_coe_file_syntax.htm

Beyond that, the particular data in the file is dependent on what core you're loading it into, and Xilinx says to look at the relevant datasheets for that core for that information.